# NSOutlineView Source List without a NIB

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I am trying to figure out how to do a source list 100% in code. I've been hacking away at SideBar demo and various SO questions/answers and have gotten close, but not quite there. I've copied my code below, this seems to work in that it does build a view, with 3 empty cells I can select. What I can't quite figure out is how to get my text to show up in those cells. I will ultimately replace that with my own view, but I'd settle for the stock rendering to work for now..

In my controller:

```
@implementation SourceListController {
    NSScrollView *_scrollView;
    NSOutlineView *_sourceList;
    SourceListDataSource *_sourceListDataSource;
}

- (void)loadView {
    _scrollView = [[NSScrollView alloc] init];

    _sourceList = [[NSOutlineView alloc] init];
    _sourceListDataSource = [[SourceListDataSource alloc] init];

    [_sourceList setSelectionHighlightStyle:NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleSourceList];
    NSTableColumn *c = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier: @"Column"];
    [c setEditable: NO];
    [c setMinWidth: 150.0];
    [_sourceList addTableColumn: c];
    [_sourceList setOutlineTableColumn:c];
    [_sourceList setDelegate:_sourceListDataSource];
    [_sourceList setDataSource:_sourceListDataSource];

    [_scrollView setDocumentView:_sourceList];
    [_scrollView setHasVerticalScroller:YES];

    [_sourceList reloadData];

    NSLog(_sourceList.dataSource == _sourceListDataSource ? @"YES" : @"NO");

    self.view = _scrollView;

}
```

And in my data source/delegate:

```
@implementation SourceListDataSource {

}

- (NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item {
    return item == nil ? 3 : 0;
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item {
    return [NSObject new];
}

- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item {
    return item == nil;
}

- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {
    NSLog(@"Here %f", tableColumn.width);
    NSTableCellView *result = [[NSTableCellView alloc] init];
    NSTextField *textField = [[NSTextField alloc] init];
    [textField setStringValue:@"Test"];
    [result addSubview:textField];
    return result;
}
```

UPDATE: Further digging tells me viewForTableColumn doesn't even get called.. I am stumped as to why..

UPDATE 2: Figured out that it was the missing column and outlineTableColumn leading to not calling the delegate method. I fixed that and updated the code, but still no text shows up.

Comment: Don't NSTableViews and NSOutlineViews default to "Cell based" content type.  Does replacing the last datasource method with - (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item  return anything.

Comment: Nope, that method does not get invoked either..

Comment: from your edit I gather that the delegate method is called but no cell views are displayed?

Comment: Correct.. I get no view..

Comment: a standard NSTableCellView already contains a property `textField`. Maybe that works. The field you added has no frame, so can't be displayed.

Comment: @XeroxDucati I just saw this after posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774492/viewfortablecolumn-not-being-called-for-child-items-in-view-based-nsoutlineview . I think our problems are identical. Did you find a solution by any chance? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate method needs changes, it won't work that way, and also doesn't make use of the new caching methods for views. Mostly, use the `NSTableCellView.textField`property instead of adding your own `NSTextField`without frame and frame constraints. So, the code that should work looks like this:

```
- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {

    NSTableCellView *result = [outline makeViewWithIdentifier:@"MyView" owner:self];
    if (result == nil) {

         // Create the new NSTextField with a frame of the {0,0} with the width of the table.
         // Note that the height of the frame is not really relevant, because the row height will modify the height.
         CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(0,0,outlineView.framesize.width,0);
         result = [[NSTableCellView alloc] initWithFrame:myRect];

         // The identifier of the view instance is set to MyView.
         // This allows the cell to be reused.
         result.identifier = @"MyView";
    }

    result.textField.stringValue = @"Test";
    return result;
}
```

All the above typed in SO.